# Getting only half of an array after passing the form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I have two forms. After submitting first form it comes to a second form where i need to get values from first form. Here is the first part of form:

```
<?php $result2 = getProcessID();?>
<form class="formcss" method="post" action="create2.php" >
<div class="row">
<div class="small-8 large-8 columns">
    <label>Process: <small style="color:red;">*</small>             
        <div class="multiselect">               
            <div class="selectBox">                 
                <select onclick="showCheckboxes()"  class="input input1 name">
                    <option>-- Select a process -- Add number of people reqired --</option>
                </select>

                <label class="tool tool1" for="name" style="top:-15px; margin-left:-14px;  left:-207px; ">Choose process and number <br> of people required</label>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="scrollable" id="checkboxes">
            <?php 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    $row[0] = cleanOutputData($row[0]); 
            ?>      
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
                    <label style="height: 38px;">
                    <input type='checkbox' style="width:20%;" name='process[]' id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value=<?php echo $row[0] ?>/><?php echo $row[0] ?>
                    </label>    
                </div>

                <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
                    <label><input type='text'style="margin-left:50%; width:20%;" name='number[]'/>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
                }
                mysql_free_result($result2);
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

It seems fine to display the values in the second form except two problems: 
1) Only half of the process is displayed
2) I can the number only for first 3 processes, but for other processes it stays an empty field.
Here is my second form:

```
$_SESSION['process'] = $_POST['process'];
$_SESSION['number'] = $_POST['number'];

$proc=$_SESSION['process'];
$len = count($proc); // getting length of an array 

$num=$_SESSION['number'];

<form class="formcss" method="post" action="create.php#err" id="reportform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="project" class="small-9 large-9 columns">
<label style="font-size: 40px; margin-left:10%;">Project <?php echo $_SESSION["title"]; ?></label>
    <label><?php for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
              {
                echo "Process:   "."$proc[$y]"."<br />";
                echo "People required:   "."$num[$y]"."<br />";         
            ?>
            <ol>
            <li class="placeholder" <?php if (isset($leader)) echo 'value="'.$leader.'"' ?>>Add people here</li>
            </ol>
            <?php                       
                }
             ?>
</label>

<br><br><br>
<div class="row">
    <input type = "submit" style="margin-left:300px; width:150px;"  name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Project" onclick="userSubmitted = true;"/>    
</div>
</div>  
</form>
```

As i said only half of the process is shown, for example, I have 'ANM KEY' process, and when i pass the value and display it on another form it displays only 'ANM'. Also I want to display number of people required for each process, but it works only for first three rows. So how i can get the wholename of the process, and display number of people required. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, I'm assuming you have `<form></form>` before and after your segments of code. And secondly, are these two forms on two different pages, or are they just on one?

Comment: Hi, yes i do have <form></form> and these two forms on two different pages

Comment: Are you using some particular add-on, or is 'multiselect' and 'selectBox' defiend by you?

Comment: @A.Lau Im using zurb foundation mixed with mine css

Comment: Hmm, no idea about zurb foundation. But double check, using print_r($_POST['process']) how many processes there are in total. Because if there are incorrect amounts, then it's definitely in the first form.

Comment: @A.Lau thanx for idea, I got the problem now, but still dont know how to solve it. Thats how array for process is look like: Array ( [0] => ANM [1] => ANM ) and here is for number:Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => 10 [12] => 15 ) so i got y only first three rows show number

Comment: can you give dummy result of what gets returned from getProcessID();

Comment: @shadab.tughlaq this function gets processes from database. There are 13 processes in the table. here is the function:  function    getProcessID()
 {
  global $con;
  $sql = "SELECT theme_name FROM `ref_themes` ";  
  return @mysql_query($sql,$con);
 }